# User cant have a second chance for input if first time enter wrong data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

So actually I have an controller that show form to user. User get that form and for example if he enter a wrong data, for example amount field is just positive numbers but user insert -1 user will get error message on screen, but when user change that value and enter for example 3 for amount and submit form, user get 404 `Whitelabel Error Page`.

So first URL is:

`http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/expenseTransaction/4`, now, user enter -1 for amount and click submit, URL is `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/saveExpense/4`, so is there any way to stay on same page and allow user to save form after he insert properly data?

I have this controller to show form:

```
@GetMapping("/expenseTransaction/{id}")
public String expenseTransaction(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Transaction transaction, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();
    model.addAttribute("userId", userId);


    model.addAttribute("transaction", transaction);
    model.addAttribute("expenseCategories", ExpenseCategories.values());

    return "expense_transaction";

}
```

This is the form:

```
<div class="container my-5">
<h3> Expense transaction</h3>
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form action="#"
                  th:action="@{/api/transaction/saveExpense/{walletId} (walletId=${id})}"
                  th:object="${transaction}" method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="amount" class="col-form-label">Amount</label> <input
                            type="text" th:field="*{amount}" class="form-control" id="amount"
                            placeholder="amount"> <span
                            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('amount')}" th:errors="*{amount}"
                            class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label for="note" class="col-form-label">Note</label> <input
                            type="text" th:field="*{note}" class="form-control" id="note"
                            placeholder="note"> <span
                            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('note')}" th:errors="*{note}"
                            class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label for="date" class="col-form-label">Date</label> <input
                            type="date" th:field="*{date}" class="form-control"
                            id="date" placeholder="date"> <span
                            th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('date')}" th:errors="date"
                            class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <label for="date" class="col-form-label">Category</label>
                        <select th:field="${transaction.expenseCategories}">
                            <option value="0">Select expense category</option>
                            <option
                                    th:each="expenseCategories : ${expenseCategories}"
                                    th:value="${expenseCategories}"
                                    th:text="${expenseCategories.displayName}"
                            ></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                               value="Update Student">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is controller to save that form:

```
@PostMapping("/saveExpense/{walletId}")
public String saveExpense(@PathVariable(value = "walletId") long walletId,
                          @Valid Transaction transaction, BindingResult result, Model model) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    UserDetailsImpl user = (UserDetailsImpl) authentication.getPrincipal();
    long userId = user.getId();

    Wallet wallet = walletService.getWalletById(walletId);

    boolean thereAreErrors = result.hasErrors();
    if (thereAreErrors) {
        transaction.setId(walletId);
        model.addAttribute("expenseCategories", ExpenseCategories.values());
        return "expense_transaction";
    }

    transaction.setWallet(wallet);
    transactionService.saveExpense(transaction, walletId, userId);
    return "redirect:/api/wallet/userWallet/balance/" + userId;

}
```

Comment: There is no `id` value sense `walletId` will resolve to nothing leading to a wrong URL. So check the URL that is being generated.

Comment: I put `transaction.setId(walletId)` after `if(result.hasErrors())` but its still same URL after submit button

Comment: The 404 clearly indicates you are posting to the wrong URL, that **or** your redirect isn't working. Check your logs and errormessages, for now there is too little information.

Comment: When I get form url is `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/expenseTransaction/5` with 5 as ID at the end and that is fine, when I insert wrong data and click submit I get error on screen and URL is this `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/saveExpense/5` now if I again insert wrong error it still should be `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/saveExpense/5` but it is `http://localhost:8080/api/transaction/saveExpense/` without `5` as ID at the end

Comment: Which is what I hinted at in my comment. There is no `id` property in your model, setting it on the transaction won't help. You need to add a property `id` with the proper value to the `model`. The problem is that initially your property is `id` but in your submit your path variable is suddenly `walletId` now when re-rendering the page no more `id` but a `walletId` is in the model. So the URL generation for `th:action` fails. Put the `walletId` in the model as `id`.

Comment: In Form you can see I have `th:action="@{/api/transaction/saveExpense/{walletId} (walletId=${id})}"` on tutorial I'm watching it stays like this for example `.../{walletId} (walletId=${wallet.id})}"` but I dont know if that can be a problem since at first and also my form works when all fields are fine

Comment: Can you give me some example how to insert that than? I'm watching some tutorial, this is repo https://github.com/RameshMF/springboot-thymeleaf-crud-tutorial/blob/master/src/main/java/net/javaguides/springboot/tutorial/controller/StudentController.java and I did same like he did

Comment: So you are half and half following a tutorial and wondering why it doesn't work. What you have is different then the tutorial and thus is break (see my previous comment). So no you didn't do as they did. `${id}` isn't `${wallet.id}`. Also in their tutorials the name of the `@PathVariable` doesn't change (as it does in yours). As I stated -> * The problem is that initially your property is `id` but in your submit your path variable is suddenly `walletId` now when re-rendering the page no more `id` but a `walletId` is in the model. So the URL generation for th:action fails.*

Comment: Okay, maybe you are right, but my controllers are similar to him, he also have path variable at the end of URL and other stuff like me, so I tried to combine that from him and make to work on my own

Comment: I know it isnt, i just gave example

Comment: Similar isn't the same, as stated twice now, your path variables names change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your code.

Your get method is defined with `@GetMapping("/expenseTransaction/{id}")` and your POST method is defined with `@PostMapping("/saveExpense/{walletId}")`.

The GET method will expose a variable named `id` in your model and fill that with the value of the path variable.

Your POST method will expose a variable named `walletId` in your model and fill that with the value of the path variable.

In your `th:action` you expect the `id` to be filled. Which is true for the GET not for the POST because the names are different.

Either fix your path variable names, or explicitly add `id` to the model in the POST method with the value from `walletId`.